# Folder Compare against AD Domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directory

I'm trying to clean up our storage from legacy users that no longer exist and getting misc results.

I have a share with all usernames as folder names (ex. `\\storage\homedir\joeblow`) AD username: Joeblow. Throughout various years users have been removed from the domain but the folders were never removed from the share. So I am walking the share and using that to query the domain to find if said user still exists. I seems to work most the time and fail randomly. Not sure why, because manually sometimes the code will execute fine. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$folders = dir \\storage.domain.edu\C$\homedir3 | where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
$folder4 = "\\storage.domain.edu\C$\homedir4"

function New-Folder($Name, $Size) {
    $folderList = New-Object PSObject
    $folderList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
    $folderList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Size -Value $Size
    $folderList | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name User -Value $User
}

foreach ($i in $folders) {
    Write-Host "Folder presently is folder $i"
    #$ADuser=Get-ADUser -Filter {$i.sAMAccountName.ToUpper() -eq"$i"} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=UserAccounts,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=edu"
    #$ADuser=Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -eq $i} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=UserAccounts,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Property samaccountname
    $r = "\\STORAGE.domain.EDU\HOMEDIR\$i"
    $r = $r.ToUpper()
    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter {sameaccountname -eq $i} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=UserAccounts,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Property homeDirectory, samaccountname

    if (!$ADuser) {
        Write-Host "Null yo"
        $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter {homeDirectory -eq $r} -SearchBase "OU=Active,OU=UserAccounts,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=edu" -Property homeDirectory, samaccountname
    }
    $ADname = $ADuser.samaccountname.ToUpper()
    $ADuser = $ADuser.homeDirectory
    $ADuser = $ADuser.toupper()
    Write-Host "R be this: $r and equal $ADuser"
    #Write-Host "The person's folder name is:  $ADuser"
    #$iUp = $i.ToUpper()

    Write-Host "The folder's is: $i"
    if ($ADuser -eq $r) {
        Write-Host "User: $ADname is in HomeDir3 $ADuser"
    } else {
        #(Test-Path "$folder4\$ADuser".trim()) {
        #$notFound = $i

        $folderList = New-Folder -Name $ADuser -User
        Write-Host "$ADname failed"
    }
}
#}

Write-Host "$folderList"

#$leftOvers = Compare-Object $folder4 $notFound
#Write-Host " Here is whats left $leftOvers"

#$i | Out-File -append "C:\deadaccounts.txt"
```

Comment: So, what is your question? What doesn't work as expected? Your code "fails randomly" ... *how*?

Comment: The query will fail despite the user existing

Comment: I did find something related to performance that may help. AD Objects are indexed, classes are not. You will get better performance when using that for a filter. Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter {(&(objectCategory=person)(name=z*))}   http://use-powershell.blogspot.com/2013_01_01_archive.html  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/03a28ac4-0028-4195-9a01-2c442d61575a/using-getaduser-to-search-for-enabled-users-in-entire-domain-filter-?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: "The query will fail" ... *how*? Are you getting an error? And which query exactly? Is `sameaccountname` a typo in your question, or is that what you actually have in your script?

Comment: Yea sorry despite all the attributes existing the query will return a null value. So it will fail in the function

Comment: Again, which query exactly? Do you mean your function `New-Folder` doesn't return anything, or does one of the AD queries not return a result?

Comment: the AD queries return a null value when i compare them to $r or the uppercased folder variable it fails out regularly. Manually the commands seem to run fine. Its quite confusing.

Comment: Output the two values to see if they actually are what you think they are: ``"_{0}_`n_{1}_" -f $r.ToUpper(), $ADuser.homeDirectory.ToUpper()``. Also, don't re-use variables. It hurts more than it helps.